# Intermediate steps of the integration of a compartmental equation

Tags: integration

I don't know how equation (3) was derived from equations (1) and (2). Could you please help with the intermediate steps or the integration rules that have been applied? Many thanks!

$$C_p(t)=\sum_{i=1}^3 a_ie^{-m_it}$$    (1)
$${dC_t\over dt}=k_{ep}(C_p(t)-C_t)$$    (2) 
$$C_t(t)=k_{ep}\sum_{i=1}^3{a_i(e^{-k_{ep}t}-e^{-m_it})\over m_i-k_{ep}}$$ (3)

Comment: Do you have some initial value or so, because there should probably be some integration constant appearing (in the end in front of $e^{-k_{ep}t}$), but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

the notation makes this problem look trickier than it really is to clarify the situation you could write equation (2) as 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+ky=g(x)$$

where $y(x)= C_t(x)$ and $g(x)=k \sum_{i=1}^3 a_ie^{-m_ix}$

the solution is then the sum of the homogeneous and particular solutions. The homogeneous solution is clearly $y_h(x)=c e^{-kx}$

To get the particular solution use an integrating factor. 
Consider $f(x)\equiv \mu(x)y(x)$

$$ f' = \mu y' + \mu' y = \mu(-ky+g(x))+\mu' y = (\mu' - k \mu )y + \mu g(x)$$

choose $\mu(x)$ to be a solution of $\mu' - k \mu=0$ i.e. $\mu(x)=e^{kx}$

then $f(x)$ can be found by integrating $f'=\mu g$

the particular solution is thus...

$$ y_p(x)= e^{-kx}\int_0^x e^{ks}g(s)ds = ke^{-kx}\int_0^x e^{ks}\sum_{i=1}^3 a_ie^{-m_is}ds = k e^{-kx}\sum_{i=1}^3 \int_0^x a_ie^{(k-m_i)s}ds  $$

$$= k e^{-kx}\sum_{i=1}^3  \frac{ a_i(e^{(k-m_i)x}-1)}{k-m_i}= k \sum_{i=1}^3   \frac{a_i(e^{-m_i x}- e^{-kx})}{k-m_i}  $$

It looks like your initial conditions must have been $y(0)=0$ which forces you to choose $c=0$

so

$$ y(x) = y_p(x) = k \sum_{i=1}^3   \frac{a_i(e^{-k x}- e^{-m_ix})}{m_i-k}$$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation as

$$\frac{d}{dt} [C_t e^{k_{ep} t}] = k_{ep} C_p(t) e^{k_{ep} t}$$

This equation may be integrated.  The sought-after result follows if your initial condition is $C_t(0)=0$.